# Trying to INSERT in db but keep getting Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've read all the postings that have to do with this but can't figure it out. I'm trying to insert into a database from a form but when I hit the submit button and pass BookingName to the code behind, I get "Keyword no supported: 'metadata'". I imagine my problem is in the web.config. Any help would really be appreciated. Still getting the hang of .NET

Here's the error:

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

**Source Error:**

```
Line 20:     {
Line 21:         string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CateringAuthorizationEntities"].ConnectionString;
Line 22:         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
Line 23:         string sql = "INSERT INTO tbBooking (BookingName) VALUES "
Line 24:                     + " (@BookingName)";
```

C# Code:

```
private void ExecuteInsert(string name)
{
    string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CateringAuthorizationEntities"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    string sql = "INSERT INTO tbBooking (BookingName) VALUES "
                + " (@BookingName)";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
        //param[0] = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 20);
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@BookingName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

        param[0].Value = name;

        for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
        }

        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Insert Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}

protected void BtnCatering_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        //call the method to execute insert to the database
        ExecuteInsert(BookingName.Text);
        Response.Write("Record was successfully added!");
    }
}
```

Web.Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="CateringAuthorizationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.CateringAuthorization.csdl|res://*/App_Code.CateringAuthorization.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.CateringAuthorization.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxxxxx;initial catalog=CateringAuthorization;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the exception detail?

Comment: @M.Babcock System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'. Do you want the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your connection string in the web.config it contains the word metadata.  Your connection string should be used be the Entity Framework. Look at using the Entity Framework to execute your command.

You could create an [EntityConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.aspx)

Comment: It works by changing this line: connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.CateringAuthorization.csdl|res://*/App_Code.CateringAuthorization.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.CateringAuthorization.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxxxx;initial catalog=CateringAuthorization;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"

to: connectionString="data source=xxxxx;initial catalog=CateringAuthorization;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework"

Comment: It will work if you change your connection string, but it will become unusable by the entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ADO.NET connection (SqlConnection) and it doesn't take the format which specified for Entity Framework.

Try
    "data source=MY-PC\SQL2008;initial catalog=CateringAuthorization;integrated security=True"